# How to load web.config while using MS Test

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mstest

I am testing some business object's Save() method. In order to save object, I need to read connection string from Configuration Manager. But all I get is null value. My settings are in web site web.config. How can I obtain during test runtime. Do I need additional configuration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The unit test project has to have it's own config file.  Add one to the project and place the connection string settings you need in it.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add that file :)